# Populating GridView with data from XML file

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

So, in a Windows 8 tablet application, I have a GridView with the following property:

```
    <Grid>
        <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource manager}, Path=TestStrings}" />
    </Grid>
```

That links to the property TestStrings in one another class.

```
public List<string> TestStrings
    {
        get
        {
            List<Location> locations = getLocations(); 

            List<string> testStrings = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < locationList.Count; i++)
            {
                testStrings.Add(locationList[i].Name);
            }

            return testStrings;
        }
    }

    public async Task<List<Location>> getLocations()
    {
        return await xmlParser.getLocations();
    }
```

If I simply populate a string List with values and return it, the GridView displays the values, no problem. However, the issue is that I need to call an async method. Most of my data will be coming from an XML file. To access an XML file, I have to pull the file from storage, which far as I know requires me to await. Here, is that method:

```
public async Task<List<Location>> getLocations()
    {
        StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile file = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("main.xml");
        XmlDocument xmlDoc= await XmlDocument.LoadFromFileAsync(file);
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlDoc.GetXml());

        List<Location> locationList =
            (from _location in xml.Element("apps").Elements("app").Elements("locations").Elements("location")
             select new Location
             {
                 Name = _location.Element("name").Value,
             }).ToList();

        return locationList;
    }
```

As you see, I await twice which forces me to make it an async method, which  means all methods that call it must be async. However, the binding property in XAML requires I access a property, which cannot be async.

I feel I am missing something. I've recently moved over from Android to start programming in Windows 8, so a lot of it is new to me. Surely, displaying data from files to the UI is a common task. What is the best way to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the type of your list from `List` to `ObservableCollection`, and see if that fixes things.  Your observation of the async behavior is spot on: modifications to a List will **not** trigger a notification to the binding engine that anything's changed, and the change is happening some unknown time later.  That notification will occur when you use [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748365.aspx).